# Test Memory Efficiency Comparing Data Structures on a Large Data Set

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist, linked-list

Is there an online resource that I can use that would simulate how a snippet of code would perform on a large data set and provide me with metrics?

Otherwise what method would you suggest to achieve this? (In my case, I specifically want to see how a LinkedList vs ArrayList would perform in terms of memory usage (being able to view bottlenecks over a period of time would be amazing) on inserting a list of things into them read from a 5GB file)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a memory profiler, Oracle JDK has two of them `visualvm` and `jmc`

You can also take a full GC and see how much memory is used by looking at the total heap size.  On HotSpot, a `System.gc();` is honoured by default.

> being able to view bottlenecks over a period of time would be amazing

This is what a CPu and memory profiler is designed for.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any tool to calculate memory usage of a specific java `Collection`.

In your case:

- In `LinkedList` any node occupies 24 bytes.
- In `ArrayList` any node occupies 4 bytes but could be more if capacity is seriously more than size.

Useful [link1](http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-1/) and [link2](http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/).